# PayPal buttons not working after 4.2.4 upgrade

Tags: buttons, paypal

After my WordPress site was updated to 4.2.4, my PayPal buttons no longer work. I can SEE the buttons, but can't click on them and go to PayPal. Hovering over the button shows no web link. I've recopied the code from PayPal several times, to no avail.

I notice that the (form) command gets screwed up every time I save/update the page where the buttons are. It puts the (/form) BEFORE the table where I have price options, near the beginning of the code. I then cut it and put it at the END of the code, click "update" and when I go back into the text mode, it has moved the  again! Very frustrating.

I posted this question on WordPress.org, but no answers as of yet. I also emailed PayPal, but no answers yet either. Any ideas?

### Thanks

**UPDATE**: I see that when I put the (form) command, it stripped it because it was HTML. So I've put parentheses on it now so it shows up.
The page on my website where I'm having the problem is:
[www.sonomabodybalance.com/workshops/](http://sonomabodybalance.com/workshops/)

You can see the PayPal button, but hovering or clicking does nothing.

I've pasted the CODE here, and I indented by 4 spaces, like the "How to Format" instructions say, but it's not working: (suggestions welcome...)
          
    
    
    
    
    Tuition:
    
    
    
    Paid by 9/11 $25.00 USD
    Paid by 9/14 $30.00 USD
    Paid after 9/14 $40.00 USD

Comment: There is no real information in this question. Post your code? Is your website on wordpress.com?

Comment: Hi Robert, I added the website URL and pasted the code here, but it's not showing, even though I did put 4 spaces before each line of code. It's stripping the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out myself. I updated my theme and all related plugins, and then magically, the PayPal code stopped getting switched each time that I clicked "update" for that page. Who knows why that was happening, but I guess just a glitch in the new version of WP/Avada working together.

Answer (score 0):

There now seem to be a number of themes and/or plugins which corrupt the PayPal button code every time the page it resides on is edited.

I've kind of got around it by copying the code to notepad the first time I create it, so it's less hassle to rewrite the code every time I want to edit the page.

I guess developers don't see it as enough of a problem to spend time fixing.